# How does OpenCV handle TCP Connections?

Tags: sockets, opencv, tcp, stream, netcat

I setup a NetCat Video Stream from my RPi and I am accessing it with OpenCV in the following way:

```
videoStream = cv2.VideoCapture("tcp://@<my_ip>:<my_port>/")
...
videoStream.release()
```

Unfortunately I cannot connect to the Stream multiple times without reinitializing it. How does OpenCV tread my tcp connection? Does .release() properly close the socket or what is the right way to close it?

Comment: These are just other options how to create a video stream. What I am interested in is how to properly terminate my connection to the RPi in order to reuse the NetCat stream in Python. I know how to do it using sockets, I just have the feeling OpenCV does not close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I do not have enough points. I had a similar issue. Ultimately, what worked for me is the run netcat with the -k option, which does allow reconnecting:

**on RPI:**

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -n -t 0 -w 640 -h 360 -fps 30 -ih -fl -l -o - | /bin/nc -klvp 5000
```

for nc, the -k option keeps the port listening after the first client disconnects, thereby allowing you to reconnect. You won't need the -v option, it just adds some verbosity.

Another alternative is to

**on receiver (Ubuntu, Win10):**

```
nc x.x.x.x 5000 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=10.60.66.237 port=5000 ! decodebin !  autovideosink
```

Python code with opencv:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("tcp://10.60.66.237:5000")   
while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame) 
      
    # the 'q' button is set as the 
    # quitting button you may use any 
    # desired button of your choice 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break
cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Disconnect and reconnect all you want :)